# "Restart from Stage" missing from Jenkins UI and Blue Ocesn

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am looking for solution where I can restart my Jenkins pipeline job from any failed step.

Sample pipeline script:

```
timestamps {
        node () {
            stage ('Checkout') {
                bat label: '', script: 'echo "stage Checkout"'
            }
            stage ('Support') {
                bat label: '', script: 'echo "stage Support"'
                bat label: '', script: '''(ROBOCOPY "\\\\Server1" "\\\\LocalFolder\\Files" "a.xml" /is /it)
                IF %ERRORLEVEL% LSS 8 (exit /B 0) else (exit /B 1)'''
            }
            stage ('Build') {
                bat label: '', script: 'echo "stage Build"'
            }
            stage ('InstallerCreation') {
                bat label: '', script: 'echo "stage Installer Creation"'
            }
            stage ('CreateNgPkg') {
                bat label: '', script: 'echo "stage Nuget Creation"'
            }
        }
    }
```

Environment:

1. Win10 Jenkins 2.230.
2. Pipeline: Declarative 1.6.0 (All dependencies installed).
3. Blue Ocean - 1.22.0.

Jenkins UI options available

[image]

BlueOcesn options available

[image]

What is missing from my system?
As per https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/ it should be available.
Checked https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45455
And also related issues on this site but none helped.

Comment: Try to rewrite the pipeline in declarative syntax. Scripted pipeline is not very well supported by Blue Ocean, so I can imagine that "restart from stage" only works for declarative pipeline. You can still have `script` sections in declarative, for anything more complicated.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the suggestion. With declarative script i got what i was looking for. But i am facing another issue, on restart the pipeline wipes the workspace as i have configured to wipe on build instead of just running the build from that stage.

Comment: Remove the wipe option and wipe the workspace by script, within the first stage.